# Short Story: Duel between a magical creature and a master accountant

Tags: identification-request

I half-remember this short story I read in a faded SF or fantasy collection:

The child of a respected sorcerer family scandalizes them by choosing a career as an *accountant*. The parents summon some sort of demon or scary relative to subdue the rebellious child, but the child is ultimately victorious by casting the "seven words of invalidity(?)": dissolution, annulment, expiry, forfeiture, termination [...] and death."

*Might* be by Robert Sheckley.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["The Accountant"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58540), a short story by [Robert Sheckley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, July 1954](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61162+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v007n01_1954-07_Gorgon776#page/n37/mode/1up). Does any of [these covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?58540) ring a bell?

**The child of a respected sorcerer family scandalizes them by choosing a career as an *accountant*.**

> Morton looked uncomfortable and scuffed his feet on the floor.
>
> "You know, not many boys have a chance to become wizards in this day and age."
>
> "Yes sir, I know." Morton looked away abruptly. In a high, nervous voice he said, "But Dad, I want to be an accountant. I really do, Dad?"
>
> Mr. Dee shook his head. "Morton, there's always been a wizard in our family. For eighteen hundred years, the Dees have been famous in supernatural circles."
>
> Morton continued to look out the window and scuff his feet.
>
> "You wouldn't want to disappoint me, would you, son?" Dee smiled sadly. "You know, anyone can be an *accountant*. But only a chosen few can master the Black Arts."

**The parents summon some sort of demon or scary relative to subdue the rebellious child,**

The scary relative was the boy's dead grandfather:

> Morton grinned, and turned back to his books.
>
> Mr. Dee was unable to stand it any longer. "Damn it," he shouted, "aren't you scared?"
>
> "Why should I be?" Morton asked. "It's only grandpa."

After Grandpa Dee fails to make an impression, Mr. Dee summons a real demon:

> "That does it, Mr. Dee said. "The boy is too cocksure of himself. We must call up Boarbas."
>
> "No!" his wife said.
>
> "What, then?"
>
> "I just don't know any more," Mrs. Dee said, on the verge of tears. You *know* what Boarbas does to children. They're never the same afterwards."
>
> "Mr. Dee's face was hard as granite. "I know. It can't be helped."
>
> "He's so young!" Mrs. Dee wailed. "It—it will be traumatic!"
>
> "If so, we will use all the resources of modern psychology to heal him," Mr. Dee said soothingly. "He will have the best psychoanalysts money can buy. But the boy must be a wizard!"
>
> "Go ahead then," Mrs. Dee said, crying openly. "But please don't ask me to assist you."
>
> How like a woman, Dee thought. Always turning into jelly at the moment when firmness was indicated. With a heavy heart, he made the preparations for calling up Boarbas, Demon of Children.

**but the child is ultimately victorious by casting the "seven words of invalidity(?)": dissolution, annulment, expiry, forfeiture, termination [...] and death."**

> The demons great horned hands reached for Morton; but quickly the boy opened the accounting book. "Save me!" he screamed.
>
> In that instant, a tall, terribly thin old man appeared, covered with worn pen points and ledger sheets, his eyes two empty zeroes.
>
> "*Zico Pico Reel!*" chanted Boarbas, turning to grapple with the newcomer. But the thin old man laughed, and said, "A contract of corporation which is *ultra vires* is not voidable only, but utterly void."
>
> At these words, Boarbas was flung back, breaking a chair as he fell. He scrambled to his feet, his skin glowing red-hot with rage, and intoned the Demoniac Master-Spell: "VRAY, HAT, HO!"
>
> But the thin old man shielded Morton with his body, and cried the words of Dissolution: "Expiration, Repeal, Occurrence, Surrender, Abandonment and Death!"
>
> Boarbas squeaked in agony. Hastily he backed away, fumbling in the air until he found The Opening. He jumped through this, and was gone.
>
> The tall, thin old man turned to Mr. and Mrs. Dee, cowering in a corner of the living room, and said, “Know that I am The Accountant. And Know, Moreover, that this Child has signed a Compact with Me, to enter My Apprenticeship and be My Servant. And in return for Services Rendered, I, THE ACCOUNTANT, am teaching him the Damnation of Souls, by means of 
>   ensnaring them in a cursed web of Figures, Forms, Torts and Reprisals. And behold, this is My Mark upon him!"
>
> The Accountant held up Morton's right hand, and showed the ink smudge on the third finger.
>
> He turned to Morton, and in a softer voice said, "Tomorrow, lad, we will consider some aspects of Income Tax Evasion as a Path to Damnation."

Comment: Great answer, as per your usual standards. (I did see it in its first revision and wondered for a moment if you were losing your touch.)

Comment: That's it! I realize now that I actually saw one of the German translations ("Utopia mit kleinen Fehlern"), hence the non-literal key passages.